# How to set the space between rows and columns in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid

If I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def func1():
    print("pressed button 1")
button1 = Button(root,text="button 1",command=func1)
button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
def func2():
    print("pressed button 2")
button2 = Button(root,text="button 2",command=func2)
button2.grid(row=0,column=1)

def func3():
    print("pressed button 3")
button3 = Button(root,text="button 3",command=func3)
button3.grid(row=1,column=0)
```

how can I set the distance between a row of column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grid` geometry manager has two options `padx` and `pady` that allows one to define extraspace, either horizontally or vertically:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def func1():
    print("pressed button 1")
button1 = Button(root,text="button 1",command=func1)
button1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
def func2():
    print("pressed button 2")
button2 = Button(root,text="button 2",command=func2)
button2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)

def func3():
    print("pressed button 3")
button3 = Button(root,text="button 3",command=func3)
button3.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
```